# Given an angle $\angle ABC$, where $B$ is the vertex, and segments $BA$ and $BC$ are not congruent, how do you bisect the angle compass only?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Im looking for a valid Mohr-Mascheroni (compass-only) construction in Euclidean geometry. What Im looking for isnt covered in any of my books and I cant find it online. Im trying to bisect an arbitrary angle defined by three points in space, unconnected by drawn line segments, but unfortunately having non-congruent legs, thus a simple arc bisection will not suffice.  I can brute force a construction if Im willing to do the work but Im wondering if there is a simpler method, say, under ten circles.

Comment: You mean no straightedge is allowed?

Comment: Good luck to you then, Mr Decliner and Time-Economist! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible construction. We start with the blue points $A,B,C$, and want to construct using only the compass a point on the angle bisector of $\widehat{ABC}$:

> [image: Mohr Mascheroni / compass-only construction of a point of the angle bisector of a given angle]

Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Mascheroni_theorem#Intersection_of_a_line_and_a_circle_(construction_#4) (the second case) we find the point $D$ of the intersection of the line $AB$ with the circle $\mathcal C(B, BC)$, centered in $B$ with radius $BC$. (Here, we construct the point $D$ such that $B$ is on the segment $AD$.)

Then we only need a point on the parallel through $B$ of the line $CD$, which is the needed angle bisector. Construct now the point $F$ such that $BFCD$ is a parallelogram. (Intersect the circles $\mathcal C(B,CD)$ and $\mathcal C(C,BD)$ and consider the "right intersection point".)

Comment: Thanks. That actually seems to work.  I was struggling to figure this out; its so simple.

Comment: I just wanted to say that even though this works, there is a slightly easier way. Points D and E are generated simultaneously when you find line ABs intersection with circle B(C).  Angle CBE is then easy to bisect with two circles.  There is no need to construct the parallelogram.  Also, constructing the intersection of line AB with circle B(C) is non-trivial. Either construction takes quite a bit of circles; this is one of the brute force methods I was referring to that I could have done on my own. Your image is very misleading with the one circle. Im still hoping there is a simpler method.